# X inside search-box-input does not clear the text

Tags: sitecore

I encountered a problem with the search boxes in my site while in IE. The search box is a sitecore component. Whenever I type in the search box and then click the X at the end, it goes back to the placeholder. However, when I click outside of the search box, the text that I previously x'ed out returns. I want the search box to be populated with the placeholder or at least remain clear. Also, there is no JS involved. I tried using JS to solve the issue but when I use developer tools, the x doesn't have a tag/name/ID, so I can't target it to manipulate it. If you require more information, please ask. [image: Here is the input search box]

[image: The second picture is when I click the x]

[image: Then when I click anywhere else, the text goes back to what I X'ed out]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [X in search box](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23789/x-in-search-box)

Comment: No, That was my question that they closed but didn't answer

Comment: I forgot to mention there is no JS involved. I tried using JS to solve the issue but when I use developer tools, the x doesn't have a tag/name/id, so I can't target it to manipulate it

Comment: Again, you have not provided enough information to help debug this issue or even replicate it. It may be a Sitecore component, but the issue is related to your HTML or Javascript, unless you are using SXA then you need to provide details to exactly what components you are using. Please provide details of all HTML/Javascript or a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/) to replicate the issue.